# jqgrid-free 4.5.0 selarrrow is not functioning as expected

Tags: c#, jquery, free-jqgrid

Let me start with that I have to use jqgrid-free version 4.5.0 as that is the version loaded into the code branch I am coding for.

I need to pull the selected information from 1 grid so I can then use that info to populate a grid later on.

the below works fine to get all the rows

```
let _modIds1 = $(pcservicerequest.modifierAuthorizationGridId).getDataIDs();
```

However, when I run the below, I get a null result for _modIds2

```
let _modIds2 = $(pcservicerequest.modifierAuthorizationGridId).getGridParam('selarrrow');
```

Is there another way to get the selected rows in jqgrid-free 4.5.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are fetching it wrong. The correct syntax is

```
$(pcservicerequest.modifierAuthorizationGridId).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Soham.  That would be the right answer, but our application has custom settings to take care of jqgrid.

The issue was that the BeforeRowSelect was returning false so the row never actually got selected but appeared to.

Comment: Oh I see. I wouldn't know that because in the question, it was not mentioned that you were using the `BeforeRowSelect` event. But I am glad you figured it out. Good luck.